# Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values in pandas select month

Tags: python, datetime

Can you help me? I want to select only 1-31 dec

```
data['InvoiceDate']=pd.to_datetime(data.InvoiceDate, format='%m/%d/%Y')
data['Date'] = data['InvoiceDate'].dt.date
December_1 = data[(data['Date'].dt.month == 12) & (data['Date'].dt.day >= 1) & (data['Date'].dt.day <= 31)]
```

and then python `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Can you help me

and I want to select only 1-31 dec